# How can I change opencart order email content as our wish? Is it possible?

Tags: php, html, opencart

Can I change the content of order email, which file it exactly refers? This is a confirmation of an online transaction placed with ######. The AuthOnly transaction totaled `$171.90` and will be processed to your account.

```
Order Number  : 10372    Approval Code : 321321 This content to This

ORDER CONFIRMATION
SUBJECT:
• Your host.com order #XXXXXXX
EMAIL MESSAGE:
• Howdy, (customer name) :
Thank you for ordering from #### We received your order (XXXXXXXX) on (00/00/00). Your work is currently being handled with the utmost care by one of the crew members. We will let you know when it’s on its way! Please visit us again soon.

Your order includes the following item(s):

Description – product
Quantity & Price – 1 @ $29.99
Shipping Method – Standard FREE

Subtotal – $29.99
Sales Tax – $ 2.10

Order Total – $32.09
```

Comment: if the answer was helpful to you, please consider selecting the best answer :) thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes of course it's possible. You can modify the content by editing the following template file:

```
/catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl
```

(assuming that you are using the default template)

But if you want to modify the subject and other stuff, you'll need to edit the order Model file:

```
/catalog/model/checkout/order.php
```

then find

```
$mail->setSubject($subject);
```

and set the $subject to whatever you want :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the changes by visiting the following model/view files.

References are as:

1. ..\catalog\view\theme\default\template\mail\order.tpl  (to doinvoice template structural or data updates)
2. ..\catalog\model\checkout\order.php (to retrieve/send any data value to order invoice template.)
3. ..\catalog\language\english\mail\order.php   (to add more language variables or any custom update.)

Hope this is useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to change powered by link then go to

```
catalog\language\english\mail\order.php
```

and change it.